# JModuleHelper::getModules returns an empty array when SEF enabled only

Tags: joomla, module, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions

I am using joomla 1.5. in this i have to include a module so i am using the code

```
 $modules =& JModuleHelper::getModules('left1');
  foreach ($modules as $module)
       {
        echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
       }
```

It  returns an array value when SEF is disabled. but  returns an empty array when SEF is enabled.I am totally confusing with this. Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to render modules loaded at position left1 use below code

```
$position = 'left1';
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
if(JModuleHelper::getModules($position)) {
  $document = JFactory::getDocument();
  $renderer = $document->loadRenderer('modules');
  $options = array('style' => 'xhtml');

  return $renderer->render($position, $options, null);
}
```